# CSS3 animation left/right direction on hover

Tags: css, animation, grid

I need som help with a boxslide issue.
I have a box grid with 3x3 boxes. The have all an image inside.
I want to be able to hover the image an slide an box with same height and with to the right, but when I hover to last box in the line it should slide to the left instead.
The slide should show what in class: compslide right

The image is visible all times.
I have different class for the right and left slide

I'm  not sure if I should use ::before/after in the css.
I have this in my html:

```
<div class="box">                                               
     <img src="/car.jpg"/>      
         <div class="compslide right">                                                          
         <a data-toggle="modal" href="#side1" aria-haspopup="true" class="modal-popup-link name">
        <h3 class="carhead">
            The is a car with 500 Hp
        </h3>                                                               
        </a>
        <p class="txtp">Description</p>                                                     
      </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with both your HTML and CSS/jQuery?

Comment: Hi Yani.
I have nothing to show. I'm starting all over agin, because it didn't work.
I've tried to mak a picture but couldn't upload because I need 10 reputations. I'm new in here. Sorry.
But I have a link to show the meaning: http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayH3#travelling-in-style

Comment: We're not going to create the whole thing for you, you need to give us what you have. If that means recreating it then you should do so

Comment: That's was not my intention. I made a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pthv/TQVz4/29/